# render scene to plane in other scene

Tags: three.js

I want to render a scene to plane in other scene, who know how to do it?
In fact, I want to create a world and there is a tv, user can have interactive in the world in tv, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how to render a scene into a texture:
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, another question, there is a plane, an box will cross it, but I only want to see this box on one side of this plane, and the box is hidden on the other side.

Comment: http://archive.acroidea.com/images/plane.jpg
I only want to see the black box on the left side, and it will have animation to move from left to right.

Comment: http://archive.acroidea.com/images/plane2.jpg
my plane is too close to the floor seems it not work correct, I'm a newer to study 3d, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: StackOverflow rules: One question and a time. And if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as good answer. Otherwise people will stop helping you.